# Best practice for retrieving a Couchbase sub document from a replica bucket?

Tags: scala, replication, couchbase, subdocument

I am using Couchbase to build an in-memory cache of `DocumentFragment[Lookup]`s. This is made easy by using the sub-document api.

```
val fragment: DocumentFragment[Lookup] = bucket.lookupIn("key").get("some.path", "some.other.path").execute()
```

Couchbase also has an interface for retrieving a `JsonDocument` from the replica attached to `bucket`.

```
val document: JsonDocument = bucket.getFromReplica("key", ReplicaMode.FIRST)
```

Does the Couchbase API provide a way to retrieve a `DocumentFragment[Lookup]` from the replica? Or are there any helper methods that transform `JsonDocument` to `DocumentFragment[Lookup]`? What is the best practice here?